# How would I create a class with a variable name in the class name?

Tags: c++, class, variables, int

So, this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class rectangle {
public:
    double width;
    double height;
    rectangle(double, double);
    double area() { return (width*height);}
};

rectangle::rectangle(double a, double b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
}

int main() {
    cout << "How many rectangles would you like to create? ";
    int rectNum;
    cin >> rectNum;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < rectNum; counter++) {
        int rectCount = 1;
        rectCount = counter + 1;
        double rectWidth, rectHeight;
        cout << "\nEnter width of rectangle " << rectCount << ": ";
        cin >> rectWidth;
        cout << "\nEnter height of rectangle " << rectCount << ": ";
        cin >> rectHeight;
        rectangle rect/*integer value of rectCount at current time*/(rectWidth, rectHeight);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As the comment section says, I would like to create a rectangle called rect, with a suffix which is the current value of the integer rectCount. How would I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about arrays, vectors etc.etc.?

Comment: There is probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve. What's your original problem ? What do you need this for ?

Comment: @deviantfan When I tried using an array, it gave the error "expression must have a constant value". Trying to use std::vector<rectangle> didn't work at all. No error message or anything. Just a red squiggly line.

Comment: @tux3 I don't have a reason for doing this, just learning C++ (classes, specifically).

Comment: You should have the input and output functions inside the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idiom is never useful in C++. The correct approach is to store your rectangles in a container like `std::vector` which will grow and shrink automatically to meet your needs. Then, you can loop through the vector and not worry about how many elements are actually in there.

```
std::vector<rectangle> rects(rectNum);

for (int counter = 0; counter < rectNum; counter++) {
    /* .. */
    rects.emplace_back(rectWidth, rectHeight);
}
```

The loop is not needed actually. `std::vector`'s constructor will take care of it for you.

```
std::vector<rectangle> rects(rectNum, {rectWidth, rectHeight});
```

You need to include `<vector>` in order to use `std::vector`.

Comment: While trying to use std::vector, I get the error message "namespace "std" has no member "vector"." How do I fix this? EDIT: Oh, ok. I assumed doing "using namespace std;" would include it. Whoops.

Comment: Thanks, you have fixed the first part of my code! Now, how would I get it to print the value of every rectangle in order? I assumed the code would be `code`cout << "The area of rect" << rectCount << " is " << rect(rectCount).area();`code`, but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

variable names must be defined at compile time so what you are trying to do will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically setting class names is not possible in C++. However, a static variable can be used to store a running count of rectangles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class rectangle 
{
    public:
        double width;
        double height;
        static int rectCount; //declare static variable
        rectangle(double, double);
        double area() { return (width*height);}
};

int rectangle::rectCount=0; //initialize static variable

rectangle::rectangle(double a, double b) 
{
    width = a;
    height = b;
    rectCount++;
}

int main() 
{
    cout << "How many rectangles would you like to create? ";
    int rectNum;
    cin >> rectNum;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < rectNum; counter++) 
    {
        int rectCount = 1;
        rectCount = counter + 1;
        double rectWidth, rectHeight;
        cout << "\nEnter width of rectangle " << rectCount << ": ";
        cin >> rectWidth;
        cout << "\nEnter height of rectangle " << rectCount << ": ";
        cin >> rectHeight;
        rectangle rect=rectangle(rectWidth, rectHeight);
        cout<<"rectCount value: "<<rectCount;
      }

return 0;
}
```